# Asp.Net Core Web Api and Vue.js client with IIS

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core, iis, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create an app with Asp.Net Core (.NET 6.0) as backend and Vue.js as frontend. I've created the .NET project inside Visual Studio 2022, added SPA Extensions and finally my Program.cs file look like this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Used by single page application requirements.
builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(options =>
{
    options.RootPath = "wwwroot";
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseStaticFiles();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
}

app.UseSpa(configuration =>
{
    configuration.Options.SourcePath = "wwwroot";
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        configuration.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:5002");
    }
});

app.Run();
```

Deploying code with setttings:

- Delete existing files
- Configuration `Release`
- Target `net6.0` Framework
- Target `win-x64` Runtime

Produce me a folder containing wwwroot folder with frontend files and many files for my backend application. I put them in an application inside iis server with an application pool configured as:

- .NET CLR Version 4.0
- Integrated pipeline mode

But my application can only load index.html file but not any .js or .css.

My application has a binding like this:
https://app.domain.it/app-name and she try to open https://app.domain.it/filename.ext file each time, failing, since file is in a https://app.domain.it/app-name/wwwroot/file.ext and he's searching for https://app.domain.it/file.ext

Anyone could help me?

Edit 1: since I've selected Self-contained mode, I don't need the .NET 6 runtime installed on server host, right?

Comment: What do you mean, it cannot load .js or .css? Is the server giving 404 for those files? Are those files on the server? Permissions?  Did it work from VStudio before putting it on a server?

Comment: @tgolisch it give me `GET https://app.domain.it/js/chunk-vendors.1e77804d.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`. It work in VS with those settings and I can use vue-router and vue js entirely without issues. Permissions are ok I think, `TrustedInstaller` user has all permissions.

Comment: @tgolisch since I've selected Self-contained mode, I don't need the .NET 6 runtime installed on server host, right?

Comment: You might read from FRT on what's wrong with those files, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to create two different Application Pools and then deploy the .net core solution as your API (a) and the vue-app as your UI (b) separately.

(a) Standard Deployment with **neither** a project reference to UI-project nor a configuration of the pipeline regarding Static and default Files (*app.UseStaticFiles(); app.UseDefaultFiles(); not necessary* )
[image]

(b) right click on vue project in VS and "Open in Terminal" -> then **npm run build** -> then go to dist folder and copy content to physical path for respective application pool on IIS

[image]

Solution worked for me. Let me know if it is a solution for you as well and if you have any questions. Hope I could help you.